# UTC DateTime issue in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

In my console application I set UTC Date Time value:

```
class Program
{
   static readonly DateTime batchDateTime_UTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Then in Main I'm using above variable in method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Parallel.ForEach(lst_Systems.AsEnumerable(), item =>
     {
          GetRecordsForTimeRange(item.IP, batchDateTime_UTC);
     }
}
```

This method is inserting data into database.
My problem is than when I'm checing batchDateTime_UTC value in database it has two different values:

```
2015-09-17 10:03:00.000
2015-09-17 10:03:36.000
```

Comment: can you show us a bit more of how the data is written to the database?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just run the program twice, 36 seconds apart?

Comment: seems like its taking 36 seconds for you to add your item to database more code will be helpful

Comment: @simonalexander2005 - I'm using SqlBulkCopy to copy data.

Comment: @AakashM I'm sure that the program is not started twice because time difference is only for some range of IPs

Comment: @Kayani - I'm adding BatchDateTime value in SELECT query and it is passed as a parameter so I don't think it have any affect on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue was caused by my stored procedure which was inserting blank values into table in case no records were found in Source table.
I had CONVERT(nvarchar(100), @BatchDateTime) and I changed it to CONVERT(nvarchar(100), @BatchDateTime,120) and now seconds are not cut.